# javascript return new line

Tags: javascript, tinymce, output, return-value

Simple question, I'm trying to output some text using javascript, and I want to have a new line between some of my text. The following code is what I'm using currently:

```
{
                text: '1/2 + 1/2',
                value: '[one_half]...[/one_half]\n[one_half]...[/one_half]',
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent(this.value());
                },
```

And this outputs

```
[one_half]...[/one_half] [one_half]...[/one_half]
```

how do I make it so my outputted text is:

```
[one_half]...[/one_half]
[one_half]...[/one_half]
```

Comment: What's `editor`? Where's this content ending up?

Comment: web browser - it's actually adding text to tinyMCE editor in wordpress

Comment: Have you heard about the `<br>` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `<br/>` instead of `\n`..

Answer (score 1):

If it's ending in the web-browser (I don't know your special case) try using `<br/>` instead of \n

Answer (score -2):

try escaping `\n` with single quotes and put the whole string into double quotes